# input validation does not work - form gets submitted anyway?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm creating a website with a form and I can't get the validation to work, and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've tried everything I can think of. The PHP works and it will submit, but it will always submit, and won't stop itself from submitting.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="En">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="a website for carley Knight art">
  <meta name="keywords" content="art artist painter painting store fine-art">
  <link rel="favicon icon" href="Images/favicon.ico">
  <title>Carley Knight Art</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="slicknav.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slicknav@1.0.8/dist/jquery.slicknav.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/final.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#nav_menu').slicknav({
        prependTo: "#mobile_menu"
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/Pink%20Stationery%20Literacy%20Google%20Classroom%20Header.png" alt="header"></a>
  </header>
  <Nav id="mobile_menu"></Nav>
  <nav id="nav_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="current" href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="Blog.html">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="Shop.html">Shop</a></li>
      <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <section>
      <div id="top">
        <h1>Homepage</h1>
        <p>Welcome to Carley Knight Art!</p>
      </div>
      <img src="Images/IMG_2995-768x1024.jpg" alt="carley knight and art" class="center" id="carley">
      <p>Hello My name is Carley Knight and I'm an artist living in Milwaukee, WI. I make abstract art in a variety of different mediums, including fibers, acrylics, and digital.</p><br>
      <button id="readMore"><a href="About.html">Read More</a></button>
    </section>
    <aside>
      <form action="sendmail.php" method="post" name="contact_form" id="contact_form">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>sign up now!</legend><br>
          <p>Sign up for my email list and get a free mini coloring book!</p><br>
          <img src="Images/minicoloirngbook.jpg" alt="mini coloring book"><br>
          <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"><span>*</span><br>
          <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"><span>*</span><br>
          <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email"><span>*</span><br>
          <label for="verify">Verify Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="verify" id="verify"> <span>*</span><br>
          <div id="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign Up">
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <script>
          $("#contact_form").validate();
          debug: true
        </script>
      </form>
    </aside>
  </main>
  <footer>&copy;copywrite 2021 Carley Knight Designs</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't load two versions of jQuery.

Comment: You don't have any validation options specified in your call to `$("#contact_form").validate()`. What are you expecting it to check?

Comment: which version should I get rid of?

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by that? I'm trying to validate the form and make sure that the options are filled in

Comment: If you want to make sure the options are filled in, you need to put `required` in the input tag, or use `rules:` in the `.validate()` options to indicate which fields are required.

Comment: You should probably read [the documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) to find out how to use the plugin...
Note that the `debug: true` you have in there does nothing; it has to be sent to the `validate` method, like `validate({ debug: true })`.

Comment: You are also calling `.validate()` inside of the `<form></form>` container, which I doubt will work, since the `<form>` needs to be fully constructed before you can initialize validation.  Move your `.validate()` into the document ready function in the head, and as stated, go read the documentation and look at sample code.

Answer (score -1):

In **HTML** all you have to do is give element **input** the attribute **required**.

If you wish for more **advanced validation** then you have to do it in **javascript**.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required>
  <input value="GO" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This does not even begin to answer the question.